# Status shows offline all the time even if the user is online (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem with user status, but it shows offline status all the time even though the user is online.

Code:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

class user(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_ready(self):
      print("userpy is ready? maybe")
  
  @app_commands.command(name='user', description='sssomething about user')
  @app_commands.describe(member='username')
  async def user(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member = None):
      member = interaction.user if not member else member
      
      if member.bot:
        embed = discord.Embed(title='woah, bot info', description=f'{member.mention} <---- booot')

        embed.add_field(name="Status", value=member.status)
        embed.add_field(name="bot?", value='Yes')
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'{interaction.user}', icon_url=interaction.user.avatar)
    
      else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title='woah, user info', description=member.mention)

        embed.add_field(name="Status", value=member.status)
        embed.add_field(name="bot?", value='No')
        embed.set_footer(text=f'{interaction.user}', icon_url=interaction.user.avatar)
    
      await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
      
async def setup(client):
  await client.add_cog(user(client))
```

I tried changing member.status to member.activities but it didn't work. I also saw another similar question but I don't really understand how to insert intents.members into cogs :/

I also have a question about how I could make it detect a bot in the same column as a regular user. Now I have to do 2 columns for bot and user.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable the precense intent for your bot.

> Go to https://discord.com/developers, select your application, go to `Bot`, scroll down to `Privileged Gateway Intents` and enable the `Presence Intent` thing.

[intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L203I.png)

As far as I know, you also need to specify in your code to use the intent you just enabled.

```py
...
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.presences = true

# use intents for your bot
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents)
```

Comment: Everything you wrote I have done and it still doesn't work (I mean I had it before)